# Fail to create the Python virtual environment using the virtualenv command on Mac

Tags: python, macos, flask, virtualenv

I am working on a Flask project. In order to create the Python virtual environment inside a folder, I use the virtualenv command

```
$ virtualenv venv
```

However, the Terminal shows

```
OSError: Command /flask/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Could anyone please help me with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using conda?  There was apparently a conda bug that could cause this sort of problem (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367).  The solution for that was to use python 2.7.9.

Comment: @molecule Using Python 2.7.9 is a solution to this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ShalabhAggarwal It still not works by duplicating methods mentioned there. Thanks all the same.